# "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema."

Tags: python, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, invoice

I am using the PayPal invoice in python, and as the title says, I get this error. The thing is, is that in Postman, creating a draft invoice fine; and in python creating the draft invoice is the only issue I have. I did do this yesterday and I had no errors.

If i'm gonna be honest I think it is something with the data but i copied it (for testing) from here (and changed the details i needed to change): [https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/#:~:text=%7B%0A%20%20%22detail%22%3A%20%7B,%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/#:%7E:text=%7B%0A%20%20%22detail%22%3A%20%7B,%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Response number is 400 if thats any help

## Python code creating  draft invoice

```
import requests
import json
token="my token would be here"
link="https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices"
headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
}
with open("Json Files\draft.json","r") as file:
    data=json.load(file)

response=requests.post(link,data=data,headers=headers)
print(response) #reponse 400

with open("Json Files\Result.json","w") as file:
    json.dump(response.json(),file,indent=4)
```

## Json result data data

```
{
    "name": "INVALID_REQUEST",
    "message": "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",
    "debug_id": "30d2ac87b6223",
    "details": [],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected this:
[https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/#:~:text=of%20the%20invoice.-,Step%20result,W44B%2DKRGF%2DJM6R%2D26VU%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22method%22%3A%20%22GET%22%0A%7D,-2.%20Send](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/#:%7E:text=of%20the%20invoice.-,Step%20result,W44B%2DKRGF%2DJM6R%2D26VU%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22method%22%3A%20%22GET%22%0A%7D,-2.%20Send)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API is expecting string, not dict

`response=requests.post(link,data=json.dumps(data),headers=headers)`

Comment: Thanks for that, but what actually is json.dumps? I know "dump" but what is "dumps"

Comment: [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)

Comment: @Tang0 if this solve your problem, then you can accept the solution

Comment: oh sorry it said to wait a couple of minutes and I just forgot.